# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: in colab notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pip, google-colaboratory, spacy

i tru to install spacy in colab notebook with `pip install spacy==1.9.0`
but i'm getting this erreo : `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7jr3zlye/cytoolz_23cdfd0a6fa64160902d81c2875437cc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7jr3zlye/cytoolz_23cdfd0a6fa64160902d81c2875437cc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-kz6m7x1f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/cytoolz Check the logs for full command output`
how to fix this error plz.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your forgot `!` before `pip install`.

The right command should be `!pip install spacy==1.9.0`

You can learn more about Colab Notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb).

**EDIT:** If it doesn't work, try to use `apt` before pip:

`!apt install spacy`

Comment: but i'm getting the same error, I don't know why he doesn't accept this version.

Comment: I edited my answer with another step before pip install.

Comment: when i tru !apt install spacy ; i'm getting this : Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package spacy .... and when i try !pip show spacy  ; i'm getting packate not found : spacy

Comment: Did you try to simply import `spacy` in the notebook without installing it ?
I never used spacy in Colab Notebook, so I can't tell you more about it.

Comment: yes i try import spacy but he get error : no module named spacy

Comment: but when I run !pip install spacy, it works, but I need version 1.9.0 to run the agorithm lda2vec